# pass the contents of a file as a parameter in python

Tags: python, parsing

I am trying to download the files based on their ids. How can I download the files if i have their IDS stored in a text file. Here's what I've done so far

```
import urllib2

#code to read a file comes here

uniprot_url = "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/"  # constant Uniprot Namespace

def get_fasta(id):

    url_with_id = "%s%s%s" %(uniprot_url, id, ".fasta")
    file_from_uniprot = urllib2.urlopen(url_with_id)

    data = file_from_uniprot.read()
    get_only_sequence = data.replace('\n', '').split('SV=')[1]
    length_of_sequence =  len(get_only_sequence[1:len(get_only_sequence)])
    file_output_name = "%s%s%s%s" %(id,"_", length_of_sequence, ".fasta")


    with open(file_output_name, "wb") as fasta_file:
        fasta_file.write(data)
        print "completed"

def main():
    # or read from a text file
    input_file = open("positive_copy.txt").readlines()
    get_fasta(input_file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) returns a list of lines in file. 
According to an oficial documentation you can also amend it

> For reading lines from a file, you can loop over the file object. This is memory efficient, fast, and leads to simple code.

So I guess your code may be rewritten in this way

```
with open("positive_copy.txt") as f:
    for id in f:
        get_fasta(id.strip())
```

You can read more about `with` keyword in [`PEP-343`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) page.

Comment: And `.readlines()` is not needed. The file object will yield each line upon iteration.